# Запятая в предложении "Нож вошел в дверь(,) словно в масло"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот

Как правильно? И почему, если не трудно.

Comment: Вошел без стука и остановился в дверях. (Борис Васильев. Были и небыли.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Нож вошел в дверь, словно  в масло.**

СЛОВНО, I. союз. (в сравнит. оборотах и сравнит. придат. предл.). **Как, точно, будто.** Крадётся, с. кошка. Несётся, с. угорелый. Смотрит, с. сыч.

**Правило**

**СЛОВНО**,  Союз. То же, что «как будто». Синтаксические конструкции с союзом «словно» **выделяются знаками препинания, обычно запятыми.** [https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/653/словно](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/653/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Пояснение

**Союзы СЛОВНО и КАК являются синонимами,** но обороты с союзом СЛОВНО обособляются чаще, в то время как обороты с союзом КАК могут обособляться факультативно (в зависимости от интонации).

Союз КАК является **универсальным,**  а союз СЛОВНО в большей степени специализирован на недостоверное (гипотетическое) сравнение.

Обороты с союзом СЛОВНО не обособляются **в особых случаях**: фразеология, в составе сказуемого, в роли частицы.

**Примеры оборотов с союзом КАК (обособленных и необособленных):**

1) Гвозди вбивались с одного удара, входили в дерево, **как в масло.** [Л. Г. Матвеева. Продлёнка (1987)]

2) Вошла ей в бедро **как в масло.** [Андрей Колесников. 1997.11.24]  Предложение мало распространено, ударение падает на сравнительный оборот, паузы нет.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на сравнительный оборот. Помимо **словно**, ещё запятыми выделяются обороты, начинающиеся на **будто**, **как будто**, **нежели**, **чем**, **точно**, **что**.

Так что должно отделяться запятой.